# У нас возник спор. Я считаю, что запятая в предложении не нужна

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, субстантивация

*Заплативший 2000 рублей вместо обычной цены(,) получит книгу в печатном формате.*

Запятая не нужна. Правильно?
Не могу человеку это доказать. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, Вы правы. Причастие *заплативший* в этом предложении переходит в разряд существительных (субстантивируется) и является подлежащим. Между главными членами предложения запятая не ставится, если между ними нет обособленных оборотов.

Но предложение, на мой взгляд, не идеальное. Без перестройки читается так, словно заплативший "вместо обычной цены получит книгу".
Можно просто поставить скобки:
*Заплативший 2000 рублей (вместо обычной цены) получит книгу в печатном формате.*
Или переделать:
*Тот, кто заплатит 2000 рублей вместо обычной цены, получит книгу в печатном формате.

Заплатив 2000 рублей вместо обычной цены, вы получите книгу в печатном формате.*